# How to view the top of the page after displaying an error or success message in a clientScript

Tags: netsuite

In a process of creating a TXT file a search in the current sublist is made to check a specific field, and a comparison is made with a field in the header. Either the TXT is created, followed by a confirmation message, or an error message is displayed prompting the user to fill in the fields that are required. In both cases the message is displayed at the top of the page, but the focus is at the end of the sublist. I would like to know how to display the top of the page after displaying the error or success message.
I'm on a clientScript.

I have not found a way to display the page showing the header, so the user does not have to scroll the page to the top.

function exportation() {
    try {

```
  ... some code.....

  var validateGuarantor = 
  validateFillGuarantorField(cr,arrPaymentProcessLine); // return 0 or 1

  if (!validateGuarantor) { // 0

    var myMsgError = message.create({
      title: "ERROR",
      message: messages.message00012,
      type: message.Type.ERROR });
       myMsgError.show(); // Please, fill the guarantor field

... some code ....                


  if (fileContent) {

 .....exportation file code .....


  var myMsgConfirmation = message.create({
    title: "SUCCESS",
    message: messages.message00013,
    type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION });
    myMsgConfirmation.show(); // success


  } 
} catch (ex) {
  throw ex;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a client script, you have access to the native JavaScript methods available in the browser.

1. You can use the browser's `window.scrollTo()` method - eg: `scrollTo(0,0);`
2. You could use an `alert()` instead of the NetSuite message module, which would allow you to show the message where it's visible without moving from the place the user is working on.

Comment: I had tried this command, but it did not work. I tried again ... same result.

Comment: Interesting...what browser are you using?  Have you tried running the `scrollTo()` method in the browser's dev tools console to test?  Also, did you try with `alert()`?

Comment: Work´s. Thank you very much